# Difference between ArrayList with safe call operator and Not Null Assertion Operator in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have four ArrayList below,  I am confusing ArrayList with safe call operator and Not Null Assertion Operator like that, even I know what is the meaning of `?` and `!!` in Kotlin, Any one can explain it for me?, how can I explain those four ArrayList situation? thanks.

```
ArrayList<User?>?, ArrayList<User?>, ArrayList<User>? and ArrayList<User>
```

or

```
ArrayList<String?>?,ArrayList<String?>,ArrayList<String>? and ArrayList<String>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These uses of `?` in a type have nothing to do with safe calls or non-null assertions.

Succinctly:

A `?` inside the list type `<>` like `ArrayList<User?>` means the list can hold null values.

A `?` after the complete type of the list like `ArrayList<User>?` means the list itself can be null.

Having `?` in both places like `ArrayList<User?>?` means both. It's a list that can hold null values and might be null itself.

Without any question marks, it's a List that is not null and cannot hold null values.

Comment: ,tnx alots, how can comment for ArrayList<String>

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, but whatever is inside the `<>` is the type of object the list can hold.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that'll help you clear that out:

```kotlin
var nullableArrayOfNullableItems: ArrayList<User?>?
// you can do that
nullableArrayOfNullableItems = null
// you also can do that
nullableArrayOfNullableItems = arrayOf(null)

var arrayOfNullableItems: ArrayList<User?>
// you CANT do that
arrayOfNullableItems = null
// you can do that
arrayOfNullableItems = arrayOf(null)

var nullableArrayOfNonnullableItems: ArrayList<User>?
// you can do that
nullableArrayOfNonnullableItems = null
// you CANT do that
nullableArrayOfNonnullableItems = arrayOf(null)

var arrayOfNonnullableItems: ArrayList<User>
// you CANT do that
arrayOfNonnullableItems = null
// you CANT do that
arrayOfNonnullableItems = arrayOf(null)
```

Comment: tnx for ur answer, I update question :)

Comment: what is the meaning of // you CANT do that or // you CANT do that, is it for which array ? :) tnx

Comment: I reviewed my code and it's clear which array it targets. So you can just paste this to .kt file and try to compile that. I feel like you're asking how nullability works at all

Answer (score 0):

This may explain the four type declarations:

```
val input = listOf("ArrayList<User?>?",
"ArrayList<User?>",
"ArrayList<User>?", 
"ArrayList<User>")
input.forEach {
    val arr = it.split(Regex("[<>]"))
    val null1 = if (it.endsWith('?')) "nullable" else "not-null"
    val null2 = if (arr[1].endsWith('?')) "nullable" else "not-null"
        println("$it : $null1 ${arr[0]} with $null2 elements in type ${arr[1].replace(Regex("[?]"),"")}")

}
```

It prints:

```
ArrayList<User?>? : nullable ArrayList with nullable elements in type User
ArrayList<User?> : not-null ArrayList with nullable elements in type User
ArrayList<User>? : nullable ArrayList with not-null elements in type User
ArrayList<User> : not-null ArrayList with not-null elements in type User
```

Comment: tnx so much understand, is it same for ArrayList<String>?

Comment: @Skysoft13 yes.